# Using triadic operator to select a perl subroutine

Tags: perl, ternary-operator, subroutine

I have a situation where I want to call one of two subroutines depending on a fairly simple test, but the parameter list is sadly complex. This would seem to read easiest using the ternary operator and works fine in C, but the perl equivalent is evading me.

Code is something like

```
$res = ($d eq 'something' ? \func1 : \func2)(parameters);
```

But perl gets very upset by the `)(` sequence and for the life of me I can't work out what to put there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use function references you have to wrap them inside subroutine invocation syntax:

```
&{ something that is a code reference } ($args)
```

So you would have to rewrite that as:

```
$res = &{ ($d eq 'something' ? \&func1 : \&func2) } (parameters);
```

The ternary operator doesn't need to be braced either:

```
$res = &{ $d eq 'something' ? \&func1 : \&func2 } (parameters);
```

Answer (score 5):

`\func1` calls func1 and takes a reference to its return value(s) - not what you want.  To take a reference to a sub, use `\&func1` (with `&` and without parentheses).

To call a reference to a sub, you either dereference it with `&BLOCK`:

```
&{ statements-yielding-a-coderef }(parameters)

# can be simplified to this if the reference is in a simple scalar:
&$coderef(parameters)
```

or with `->` (parentheses may be required because of `->`'s high precedence):

```
( expression-yielding-a-coderef )->(parameters)
```

So do either:

```
$result = &{ $d eq 'something' ? \&func1 : \&func2 }(parameters);
```

or:

```
$result = ( $d eq 'something' ? \&func1 : \&func2 )->(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $d = 'something';
my $res = &{($d eq 'something' ? \&func1 : \&func2)}('world');

print $res;

sub func1 {
  my $resp = shift;
  return 'hello'.$resp;
}

sub func2 {
  my $resp = shift;
  return 'world'. $resp;
}
```

and of course it wouldn't hurt if you use this:

```
$param = 'world';

if ($d eq 'something') {
  print func1($param);
}
else {
  print func2($param);
}
```